# Call external controller method and render the view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am using a project called MVCForum and have created a new project in the solution which, for demo purposes, let's call "ExternalApp".

Now, I have added the ExternalApp reference to the MCVForum application, and can call the controller: http://mysite[.]com/TestController

where "TestController" is my external controller. That is, the controller lives in ExternalApp.

The problem is that when I try to return the view from "Test" in TestController, the view cannot be found.

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Themes/Metro/Views/Test/Index.cshtml
~/Themes/Metro/Views/Extensions/Test/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Extensions/Test/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Test/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Test/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

The application seems to be looking within it's own project for the view, and not in the ExternalApp/Views folder. How can I get my external app to render the correct view?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212664/how-to-change-view-partial-view-default-location/19213613#19213613

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to create a custom view engine but as described [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Storing-ASP-NET-MVC-Controllers-Views-in-separate-assemblies.aspx)you have there are number of modifications you need to make:

1. In order for the views in our MVCExternalApp project to be available at runtime, they must be copied to the MVCForum output folder. Unless you wish to do this manually, you have to specifically tell each view to copy to output. This option forces the files to go into the bin folder.
   For each view, right click and select properties. Change the 'Copy to Output Directory' option to 'Copy Always'. The will ensure that the files are always put in the output when the referencing project is built. You will also want to do this for the Web.config.
2. Create a custom view engine:

   ```
   public class CustomViewEngine: RazorViewEngine 
   {
      public CMSViewEngine()
      {               
          ViewLocationFormats = new string[] 
          {
              "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
              "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
              "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
              "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
              "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
              "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", 
              "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
              "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
          };

          PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
          {
              "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
              "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
              "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
              "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
              "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
              "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", 
              "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
              "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
          };
      }
   }
   ```

*I override only PartialViewLocationFormats an ViewLocationFormats but you can override the rest of locations if needed;*

3. Register view engine in Application_Start method in Global.asax:

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
       RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

       //Remove all view engine
       ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();

       //Add Custom view Engine Derived from Razor
       ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
   }
   ```

Comment: Because of inevitable "link rot", this answer could be made better by summarizing the contents of the linked article in detail as it pertains directly to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Razor Generator](https://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) to compile your views into your ExternalApp assembly, or you can just run the two apps separately under one site.